# Dynamic IP - How to allow/deny

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic, ip

I have a private image gallery that I've used a .htaccess file to only allow our IP address and its worked great - I got this info from this site, so a big thanks!

I've run into a bit of an issue though, I now need to allow access to an external group but they use a dynamic IP address. Is this something I can still accomplish using a .htaccess file or is this a whole new animal now that I should be looking at alternative methods? Any direction would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this with a static .htaccess file. Without knowing their new IP addresses in advance.

You could set them up with a dynamic DNS service and then do a reverse lookup on the server before allowing access.

Comment: Thanks joe_archer I'll look into that! I've been reading that you can allow from a Client hostname rather then IP, sounds hopeful as well and I'll be looking into that further too :)

Comment: You could do it by host name, but anyone can set their host name to anything they like, thus circumventing your security. If you consider this question answered, please mark as answered.

Comment: Thanks Joe_Archer - I was just waiting to hear back from our internal IT team and if any other options come out of that I'd post them here as well for others. I'll mark you with the answer though. Thanks :)